# Read an input file with text (strings) and create an output (.dat) file with the values from the input file only

Tags: python

I am trying to take a text format .out file written in the form below and convert it to a data file with integers only.

The text (.out) file looks like this. It has many rows and 1 column with all the inputs in there. **Note that the numbers on the side represent the row number in notepad++**

```
1.                    Start of ipnut file
2. This file contains numbers
3. This file will need to be format from all text to only a dat file with numbers only
4. The numbers on the left of this file represent the row number from Notepad++
5.
6. See the values below
7. -----------------------------------
8. 
9. InputA  InputB  InputC  InputD  InputE
10. --------------------------------------
11.                34500.  430.0   32000
12.                54000.  730.8   27000
13.                12000.  909.2   42500
```

Now basically what I want is to create a data file (.dat) that would take the file above and convert it to below:

```
34500.  430.0   32000
54000.  730.8   27000
12000.  909.2   42500
```

So Instead of being many rows and 1 column with all strings, it would now be 3 rows and 3 columns with integers.

Would appreciate it if you could help me out here.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting an error or unexpected output? please add your code and the error message or unexpected output in your question to be able to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data from the file with `open()` and `readlines()`, then use `split()` to extract the values from the white space.

```py
def parse_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    data = []
    for line in lines[10:]: # skip to the line that contains the first value
        line = line.split()
        data.append(line)
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = parse_file('input_file.out')
    print(data)
```

Output:

```
['34500.', '430.0', '32000']
['54000.', '730.8', '27000']
['12000.', '909.2', '42500']
```

You stated that you wanted only the integers, but I notice that your sample output contains things like `34500.` which can only be represented as a string because of the trailing `.`.